# Get Users according to Role with rights

Tags: php, yii, rights

I have three tables in the db. One is `authmanager` has `rolename` and `user_id`. The second is `user` which has the usual `id`, `username` and `password`. The third table is `employee`, which has 'id', 'user_id' and the rest of the fields. The problem is that in the index page of employee i want to show the employees in tabs and according to the roles in the 'authmanager' table. How can the relations of yii be used?

I am using `rights` for managing rights and `authasignments`. I want to get all the users belonging specific `rolename`. So far i get existing roles with the help of `Rights::getAssignedRoles()`. I am new to rights so please give me a direction to work.

Comment: Are you asking for model relations or to how to retrive the data? If so, please add the relations on each model please.

Comment: You are using 3 tables to manage 1 simple logic, IMO you should use 1 table with user (id, username, password, role), and resolve authorization without relations.

Comment: When talking about rights, do you mean the [Rights extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/)?.